# Ssh MySQL download user table for multiple tables batch script - dreamhost

Tags: mysql, ssh, dreamhost

Been running a charity service for 10 years setting up basic wordpress installations and dealing with the inevitable hacks etc.  I've run out of personal time to administer it and need to service notice to everyone that I'll be discontinuing their website services from the end of this year.
I have at least 233 sites which I need to login to and gather the latest email accounts from.  I have a file with all the usernames and passwords of the SQL environment.

Assuming I have a file with usernames and passwords for each of the databases (all on the same host), can someone write a ssh script that'll download the users file (it's "salted" so db_users becomes db_zxcvg_users with the zxcvg changing on each table name) so I can bung them all an email.

Appreciate that's a bit of an ask & sounds like I'm an incompetent script kiddy with a pile of usernames and passwords - but I'm just a temp website administrator who's spending more time with his kid.

Concatenating into a CSV file would be great.  There's a few compromised accounts I also need to strip out with stupid user ids etc but I can probably do that manually quicker.

Comment: Do you have root access to the instance (can see all databases with one user)?  Or do you need to login with a specific user for each database?

Comment: Specific login for each database :(

Answer (score 1):

I'm making the assumption that you have a bash shell:

```
while read line; do 
db=$(echo $line | cut -f1 -d,)
user=$(echo $line | cut -f2 -d,)
pass=$(echo $line | cut -f3 -d,) 

mysql --database=$db --user=$user --password=$password --skip-column-names --batch --execute "select concat(column1,',', column2) from table name" >> all_users
done < credential_file
```

That assumes you have a csv file of `database,user,password` in a file called `credential_file`.  That file is redirected into the while loop at `done`.

mysql query is run from the command line, creating a csv, and dumping all the contents into a single file.  You can do post-processing on the file to clean it up.

This will put all your passwords into your bash history in plain text, so plan to nuke the bash history.  (unless you deem it low risk to keep that)

That should get you most of the way there.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Kevin!  I'll give it a bash this weekend as I work in a secure environment during the week.